# Adding git commands to bash profile

Tags: bash, git, .bash-profile

I am using OSX and wish to add a function in terminal to run a set of git commands. Therefore, I created a .bash_profile in my home directory with the code below:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export PATH="$PATH:"/Applications/microchip/xc8/v1.35/bin""

export PATH=$PATH:"/Applications/microchip/xc16/v1.25/bin"

export PATH="$PATH:"/Applications/microchip/xc8/v1.38/bin""

function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit —a -m “$1”
    git push
}
```

However, after running this code I receive the following error:

```
Seths-Air:rpt04-recursion Seth$ lazygit "test of lazygit"
error: pathspec '—a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'of' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'lazygit”' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you typed and what output you got. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
git commit —a -m “$1”
```

contains several characters which look similar to the ones the shell interprets but are in fact other characters.

First `—a` vs `-a`: Due to the longer dash this *not* interpreted as an option but as a filename. Use a standard dash/minus (`-`) here.

Second `“$1”` vs `"$1"`: Your checkin comment string will be split into separate words and the first and last word will extended with a funny character.

In all cases it looks like you either used an unsuitable editor for writing programs and scripts or you copy&pasted stuff from some site which did that mangling. You need plain ASCII characters as they are directly on your keyboard and not the "pretty-print" variants intended for humans. If in doubt, copy&paste them from here :-)

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding it using the commands on this website (https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-make-an-em-dash-on-a-mac) but I ended up getting the same character. How'd I be able to find it? Thanks

Comment: @SethShill I updated the answer. Feel free to upvote/accept my answer.